# Get @timestamp value in elasticsearch response

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm using `elasticsearch-dsl-py` to extract data from `elasticsearch`.

I want to save the value of the `@timestamp` field (`hits.hits._source.@timestamp`). But I have no clue how to deal with the fact that the `@` character is not allowed in Python.

How do I get the value from `@timestamp`? This does not work:

```
h = response.hits[0]
print(h.@timestamp)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can access that field as follows:

```
h = response.hits[0]
print h['@timestamp']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple solution. It works and is exactly what I need.